# How to pass a function as predicate to another function, When name of the predicate function is received at RunTime?

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, functional-programming, functional-interface

I receive the name of the function to be used as biPredicate at runtime. I want to pass around this biPredicate and evaluate, basically filter to get results. 
Following is my utility that defines biPredicates. I tried utilizing MethodHandle and Lambda Functions. When I use

```
new FilterUtility().execute("genericFilter");
```

> I get java.lang.AbstractMethodError

```
public class FilterUtility {

public void execute(String filterName) throws Throwable {
    ActualBean beanObject = ActualBean.builder().param1("true").param2("false").build();

    MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, Object.class, Object.class);
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle handle = lookup.findStatic(FilterUtility.class, filterName, methodType);
    BiPredicate<Object, Object> f = (BiPredicate<Object, Object>) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
            "test",
            MethodType.methodType(BiPredicate.class),
            methodType.generic(),
            handle,
            methodType)
            .getTarget()
            .invokeExact();

    resolve(beanObject, new HashMap<>(), f);
}

public static <SourceObject, TemplateObject> Map<String, String> resolve(SourceObject src,
        TemplateObject template,
        BiPredicate<SourceObject, TemplateObject> p) {
    if (p.test(src, template))
        return new HashMap<>();

    return null;
}

public static <SourceObject, TemplateObject> boolean genericFilter(SourceObject x, TemplateObject y) {
    ObjectMapper ob = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> source = ob.convertValue(x, Map.class);
    Map<String, Object> template = ob.convertValue(y, Map.class);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : template.entrySet()) {
        if (!source.get(entry.getKey()).equals(entry.getValue()))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

When I change implementation of execute to following, I dont get exceptions.

```
public void execute(String filterName) throws Throwable {
    ActualBean beanObject = ActualBean.builder().param1("true").param2("false").build();
    resolve(beanObject, new HashMap<>(), FilterUtility::genericFilter); }
```

This makes me believe that there is something wrong with the way I am trying to find the function with name and send it as a biPredicate.

Comment: i used debugger to stop once I create method handle here

 `MethodHandle handle = lookup.findStatic(FilterUtility.class, filterName, methodType);`
then  I executed 
`handle.invoke(order, new HashMap<String, String>());`

**it gives me java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. Message: MethodHandle.invoke cannot be invoked reflectively**

Comment: remove the `.generic()` in line 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the method `methodType.generic()` which will replace all parameter types and the return type with `java.lang.Object`, including primitive types. So you are transforming the target method’s signature `(Object,Object)->boolean` to `(Object,Object)->Object`, effectively creating a class with a method `Object test(Object,Object)` which will invoke your target method and box the result.

Such type mismatches are not checked by the lambda metafactory. So when you try to invoke `BiPredicate`’s method `boolean test(Object,Object)` on that generated class, an error will be thrown.

The correct method to use is `methodType.erase()`, which will replace all reference types with `java.lang.Object` but keep primitive types as-is. Though, in this specific case, you don’t need to transform the method type at all, as the target method’s type is already `(Object,Object)->boolean`, so just replacing `methodType.generic()` with `methodType` would work too.

Comment: How could I find this issue myself? Maybe some trick in debugger

Can you also share resource where I can find this information? Thinking on the line that I will be encountering more issues which would be easy to solve if I already know where to look.

Comment: I think, the [class documentation of `LambdaMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) is quiet comprehensive. Since it is mainly intended for experts (or rather, for generated code, produced by compilers or tools made by experts), it doesn’t sacrifice performance for checking all properties.

Comment: I’m afraid, to fully understand all details (like the implications of type erasure), knowing [The Java® Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) and [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html) is unavoidable.